# Where can we find information of International Physics/Astrophysics conferences?

Tags: astrophysics, soft-question

Where do you check and put them usually?
Let's make a wiki ~

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best place to look for conferences is the site of [physics world and particularly the events page](http://physicsworld.com/cws/events).

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of sites which lists conferences, e.g.

- [Conference Listing in Mathematics, Physics and Chemistry - Mandl](http://www.conference-service.com/conferences/index.html) (this one is good and aesthetic; once I attended a conference I had found there)

Also:

- Associations/societies list their conferences
- Some research groups homepages have list on conferences in their field.
- Facebook, your faculty homepage, etc

(However, none of the current solutions is perfect. I have one idea what to do... but let's wait - or contact me.)

Answer (score 0):

The CADC's [International Astronomy Meetings List](http://www2.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/cadcbin/meetings/getMeetings.pl?year=2010) is probably my favourite aggregator of international astrophysics conferences.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two more places to look:

- [SPIRES conference search](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/conferences/)
- [INDICO ar CERN](http://indico.cern.ch/)